# Use of std::vector::emplace_back

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, std

I have some class-warper for std::thread. Here is the constructor:

```
template <typename Function, typename... Args>
InterruptibleThread(Function&& fun, Args&&... args)
{
    _thread = std::thread([](std::atomic_bool * f, Function&& function, Args&&... arguments)
    {
        _flag_ref = f;
        (function)(std::forward<Args>(arguments)...);
    },
        &_flag,
        std::forward<Function>(fun)
        , std::forward<Args>(args)...
        );
}
```

And then I'm using it so (example): 
    InterruptibleThread(&SourceImageList::StartFrameProcessingStatic, this, std::ref(it))

The compiler builds this code successfuly. But now I would like to make a vector of such objects:

```
std::vector<InterruptibleThread> grp;
```

I would like to allocate it on the stack so what I'm doing is:

```
grp.emplace_back(&SourceImageList::StartFrameProcessingStatic, this, std::ref(it));
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
C2064   term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
```

Here are the options which are validated by the compiler:

```
1) grp.push_back(new InterruptibleThread(&SourceImageList::StartFrameProcessingStatic, this, std::ref(it)));
2) grp.push_back(InterruptibleThread(&SourceImageList::StartFrameProcessingStatic, this, std::ref(it)));
```

But the first one is allocating an object on the heap so I need to release it manually, and the second one makes a copy of the object.

Can I use `emplace_back` here (compiler is MSVC 2015 update 3)?

**Update**

Ok, I made some fixes based on answers. Here is the final version of this class:

```
#pragma once
#include <exception>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <windows.h>
// Synopsis
class InterruptThreadException;
class InterruptibleThread;

// Interrupt exception
class InterruptThreadException : public virtual std::exception {
public:
    virtual char const* what() const override { return "interrupt"; }
}; // class InterruptThreadException

   // Interruptible thread
class InterruptibleThread {
public:
static void InterruptionPoint() noexcept(false) {
    if (!InterruptibleThread::_flag_ref) { return; }
    if (!InterruptibleThread::_flag_ref->load()) { return; }

    throw InterruptThreadException();
} // check_for_interrupt

template <typename Function>
InterruptibleThread(Function&& fun) :
    _thread([this, fun = std::move(std::forward<Function>(fun))]
{
    _flag_ref = _flag.get();
    fun();
})
{}

InterruptibleThread(InterruptibleThread&&) = default;
InterruptibleThread(const InterruptibleThread&) = delete;

bool Interrupting() const { return _flag->load(); }

void Interrupt() { _flag->store(true); }

void Join()
{
    _thread.join();
}

bool TimedJoin(int msec)
{
    return (std::async([=]() {Join(); }).wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(msec)) != std::future_status::timeout);
}

bool Joinable()
{
    return _thread.joinable();
}

void Terminate()
{
    TerminateThread(_thread.native_handle(), -1);
}

~InterruptibleThread()
{
    if (_flag.get() != nullptr)
    {
        *_flag = false;
        Interrupt();
    }
    if (_thread.joinable())
        _thread.join()
}

private:
    static thread_local std::atomic_bool* _flag_ref;
    std::unique_ptr<std::atomic_bool> _flag = std::make_unique<std::atomic_bool>();
    std::thread _thread;
};
```

And example of use:

```
std::vector<InterruptibleThread> grp;
for (auto it : _sourceImages)
    grp.emplace_back([this, it] {
    it->StartFrameProcessing();
    it->SetImageDelay(const_cast<EngineConfig*>(GetConfig())->ImageDelay);
});
```

Comment: "Can I use emplace_back here" - did you *try*? Actually just trying would answer your question.

Comment: The second `push_back` version you provided should actually `move` the `InterruptibleThread` when pushing back to the vector rather than creating a copy - the compiler will almost certainly use this overload.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury In C++11 it will definitely move it (so the compiler doesn't do any additional optimization), as `push_back` has a rvalue overload http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back

Comment: @vsoftco Indeed, I meant to say "overload" rather than "optimisation", edited my comment now.

Comment: so I can use: "grp.push_back(InterruptibleThread(&SourceImageList::StartFrameProcessingStatic, this, std::ref(it)));" without perfromace issues, Thanks.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, the OP **did** try. As the code snippet & relevant error indicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could modernize your code and pass a lambda into `InterruptibleThread` instead of passing a function and it's arguments (i.e. bind-style).

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

struct InterruptibleThread
{
    std::thread _thread;

    template <typename Function>
    InterruptibleThread(Function&& fun)
        : _thread(std::forward<Function>(fun))
    {
    }
};

struct Test
{
    std::vector<InterruptibleThread> grp;
    void test(int x) {
        grp.emplace_back([this, x]{ t1(x); }); // <==== HERE
    }
    void t1(int x) {
        std::cout << x << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
    t.test(5);
    t.grp[0]._thread.join();
}
```

Comment: Nice. Genius is simplicity. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that the immediate problem is that the vector class is trying to instantiate the move constructor of your class, which happens to match the template signature but then fails to compile the body with `Function = InterruptibleThread, Args = {}`.  You'll need to provide an override by explicitly defaulting the move constructor.

Aside from this, a couple other points:

- As written, the constructor shouldn't work with pointer-to-member-functions and `std::reference_wrapper` arguments.  (It didn't work under gcc, and I don't see how it could have worked in MSVC.)
- It's not in the code sample, but it looks like _flag is a member variable of type `atomic_bool`.  That would prevent a default move constructor from being able to be instantiated.

Here's a revised version which compiles for me under gcc:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

thread_local std::atomic_bool* _flag_ref;

class InterruptibleThread {
private:
  std::thread _thread;

  // Need unique_ptr instead of a directly contained atomic_bool
  // to make the object MoveConstructible.
  std::unique_ptr<std::atomic_bool> _flag;

public:
  template <typename Function, typename... Args>
  explicit InterruptibleThread(Function&& fun, Args&&... args)
  {
    _flag = std::make_unique<std::atomic_bool>();

    // Use std::bind to take care of all the details of
    // calling pointer-to-member-function or pointer-to-member-variable,
    // unwrapping std::reference_wrapper arguments, etc.
    auto bound_fun = std::bind(std::forward<Function>(fun), std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    _thread = std::thread([this, bound_fun = std::move(bound_fun)]
    {
        _flag_ref = _flag.get();
        bound_fun();
    }
        );
  }

  InterruptibleThread(InterruptibleThread&&) = default;
  InterruptibleThread(const InterruptibleThread&) = delete;
};

class Foo {
public:
  void func(int& n);
};

void test_func() {
  std::vector<InterruptibleThread> v;
  Foo f;
  int n = 5;
  v.emplace_back(&Foo::func, &f, std::ref(n));
}
```

Comment: It looks to be compilable now. I also like the solution of @RustyX, it can make code more simple. Thanks!